# How to Update a Case Object using LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, case, update

I am pretty new to LWC and I am trying to create a button that allows the user to edit/update a selected case from a list view. I have looked around the web and a common solution is to use SObjects in the JS portion of the LWC instead of using an Apex controller. Most of the possible solutions to my problem use SObjects like Accounts and  Contacts but none use Case. I tried to substitute and modify the code to use Case and the fields in the Case object but I run into errors that the fields I tried to call do not exist.
Is there a way to solve my problem or does anybody have documentation on what's the correct syntax when it comes to the Case SObject like Case Id, Status Level, Priority, etc.?

Comment: Examples are given in the documentation, if you are facing some issue in that , then please share the code snippet in which you are facing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<lightning-record-edit-form>` or `<lightning-record-form>` tag to add/view/update your standard/custom sObject record.

please read [this document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-form/documentation)

check the sample code and you will soon know how to do.